# DATA TYPE MISMATCH error IN CRITERIA EXPRESSION (ms Access)

Tags: c#, ms-access-2003

please figure out the error in my code.it show

> DATA TYPE MISMATCH error IN CRITERIA EXPRESSION .

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE tbbill.*, tbgrid.* FROM tbbill INNER JOIN tbgrid ON tbbill.invoice = tbgrid.ginovice WHERE tbbill.invoice ='" + Convert.ToInt32(txtinvoice.Text) + "'", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Comment: Your `invoice` is character or numeric? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: it is numeric #soner Gonul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes are for characters, if your `invoice` is numeric typed, you need to delete these quotes like;

```
tbbill.invoice = " + Convert.ToInt32(txtinvoice.Text) + ...
```

### But don't use this way.

Always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your command and connections automatically instead of calling `Dispose` method manually.

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE tbbill.*, tbgrid.* FROM tbbill INNER JOIN tbgrid ON tbbill.invoice = tbgrid.ginovice WHERE tbbill.invoice = @invoice";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtinvoice.Text);
    // I used OleDbType.Integer in my example. You should use proper OleDbType for your column.
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                "DELETE tbbill.*, tbgrid.* 
                 FROM tbbill 
                 INNER JOIN tbgrid 
                    ON tbbill.invoice = tbgrid.ginovice 
                 WHERE tbbill.invoice = " + Convert.ToInt32(txtinvoice.Text) , con);
```

I have removed `''` from the invoice

Whereas you should always use a parameterized SQL to prevent SQL Injections

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                "DELETE tbbill.*, tbgrid.* 
                 FROM tbbill 
                 INNER JOIN tbgrid 
                    ON tbbill.invoice = tbgrid.ginovice 
                 WHERE tbbill.invoice = @invoice", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", Convert.ToInt32(txtinvoice.Text) );  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```